# How to Resolve TFS 2012 Build Error - 4264?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (4264): The command "del C:\Builds\4{Project}{Build Definition}\Binaries\{FileName}*" exited with code 1.

I noticed that the file it is trying to delete is behind two backslashes, but I have no idea how to fix the issue or where it is being called.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by two backslashes (generally path should be fine with this), the error command is called by msbuild, Microsoft.Common.targets is the msbuild target file (what to execute). The path itself doesnt seem to be final version of call try enabling diagnostic log and go trough log file to find what exactly is being called. On the other hand if its is the final path then something in project or solution files has this defined, have you upgraded to TFS 2012 recently ?

Comment: We have been using TFS 2012 for a while now, but this is one of the first CI builds, others do work fine though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a space was causing the issue, because the build server didn't put quotes around the line it was deleting.

Still not sure why it was failing on this one and none of the others, nor why it was doing the delete in the first place, but at least it is working now...